# Предикат, определяющий сумму простых чисел, не превосходящих данного

Tags: prolog

Моя задача: "Опишите предикат, определяющий сумму простых чисел, не превосходящих данного."

Что есть: предикат (если я правильно понимаю, то это предикат), позволяющий найти список простых чисел до данного. Как их теперь просуммировать?

```
is_prime(2).
is_prime(3).
is_prime(P) :- 
    integer(P), 
    P > 3, 
    P mod 2 =\= 0, 
    \+ has_factor(P,3).  

has_factor(N,L) :- N mod L =:= 0.
has_factor(N,L) :- 
    L * L < N, 
    L2 is L + 2, 
    has_factor(N,L2).

prime_list(A,B,L) :- 
    A1 is (A // 2) * 2 + 1, 
    p_list(A1,B,L).


p_list(A,B,[]) :- A > B, !.
p_list(A,B,[A|L]) :- 
    is_prime(A), !, 
    next(A,A1), 
    p_list(A1,B,L).

p_list(A,B,L) :- 
    next(A,A1), 
    p_list(A1,B,L).

next(2,3) :- !.
```

**Обновление**

В общем, я добавил в конце предиката `prime_list` еще вызов `sum_list(L,S)`, где `sum_list(L,S)` есть

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], Sum) :-
   sum_list(T, Rest),
   Sum is H + Rest.
```

В общем, меня больше всего что интересует. Грамотно я решил задачу с точки зрения ее постановки? Просто времени особенно нет, разобраться толком не успел. И еще такая проблема возникла, 2 ки в списке нет, хоть наверху и написано `is_prime(2).`

Comment: Что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: Код суммирования вроде бы верный, я думаю вам стоит удалить этот вопрос и задать вопрос о генерации списка простых чисел :-)

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko а что с ним не так?)

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko только не говорите мне, что то что я написал вообще к задаче не относится) Этого я больше всего боюсь)

Comment: Ладно, не скажу

Comment: Вроде бы прокатило) @AlexeiAverchenko